# Hibernate duplicate entry for primary key

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
public class WeeklyCare {
@EmbeddedId
private WeeklyCareIdentifier weeklyCareIdentifier;

private Double practicalCare = 0d;

private Double personalCare = 0d;

private Double healthCare = 0d;

private Double rehabilitation = 0d;

private Boolean hospitalized;

private Double totalCare = 0d;
}
```

This is the embedded id:

```
@Embeddable
public class WeeklyCareIdentifier implements Serializable {

@NotNull
@Size(max = 10, min = 10, message = "CPR must tbe exactly 10 characters")
private String cpr;

@NotNull
private Integer week;

@NotNull
private Integer year;
}
```

Here is the relevant code I use for inserting data into the database:

```
List<WeeklyCare> weeklyCareToSave = new ArrayList<>();
for(Citizen c : citizensAndSubCare.citizens){
    for(WeeklyCare wc : c.getWeeklyCare()){
        if(weeklyCareRepository.existsById(wc.getWeeklyCareIdentifier())){
weeklyCareRepository.updateWeeklyCareByIdentifier(wc.getPracticalCare(), wc.getPersonalCare(), wc.getHealthCare(),
                            wc.getRehabilitation(), wc.getTotalCare(), wc.getWeeklyCareIdentifier());
                } else {
                    weeklyCareToSave.add(wc);
                }
            }
        }
        weeklyCareRepository.saveAll(weeklyCareToSave);
```

The last line with the `saveAll()` method has caused this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry "0123456789-1" for key "PRIMARY"
```

This is very confusing to me for several reasons:

1. The key "0123456789" exists, but not with "-1" at the end. I'm not sure where it gets that from.
2. The key that it is complaining about is `cpr`, but duplicates of this column should be allowed. It should only cause an error if `week` and `year` are also the same for a row.
3. I am checking if there already exists a row with a specific `WeeklyCareIdentifier`(`cpr`, `week`, `year`) and am only inserting a new one if not. Otherwise I will update the existing one.

I'm not sure, but could `"0123456789-1"` mean `cpr=0123456789` and `week=1`? If so, that would make a little sense, because, the new data that I'm trying to insert contains a record with the same `cpr` and `week`. However, the year is different (`2018` vs. `2019`), so it should be allowed.

Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my database did not reflect my hibernate code (probably because I have `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` in `application.properties`), so the primary key for 
the `weekly_care` table was just `cpr` and `week` since I added `year` later on. I think I will have to drop the table and let hibernate recreate it.